# How to use conditional filtering of a data frame in R when trying to retain non-duplicated values in two columns

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering

I have a data frame that is organized as such:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(rep("1111", 16),rep("2222", 16)),
                 subID=rep(c(rep("100", 4), rep("200", 4), rep("300", 4), rep("400", 4)),2),
                 instance=rep(1:4, 8),
                 feature=rep(letters[1:4], 8)
                  )
```

Which looks like this:

```
> df
     ID subID instance feature
1  1111   100        1       a
2  1111   100        2       b
3  1111   100        3       c
4  1111   100        4       d
5  1111   200        1       a
6  1111   200        2       b
7  1111   200        3       c
8  1111   200        4       d
9  1111   300        1       a
10 1111   300        2       b
11 1111   300        3       c
12 1111   300        4       d
13 1111   400        1       a
14 1111   400        2       b
15 1111   400        3       c
16 1111   400        4       d
17 2222   100        1       a
18 2222   100        2       b
19 2222   100        3       c
20 2222   100        4       d
21 2222   200        1       a
22 2222   200        2       b
23 2222   200        3       c
24 2222   200        4       d
25 2222   300        1       a
26 2222   300        2       b
27 2222   300        3       c
28 2222   300        4       d
29 2222   400        1       a
30 2222   400        2       b
31 2222   400        3       c
32 2222   400        4       d
```

In the real data set, all subIDs are unique samples collected from the same ID. You can think of them as a sample collected at four time points from the same location. The subIDs 100 through 400 are each associated with one of the 4 instances (i.e.,  100 = 2, 200 = 4, 300 = 3, and 400 = 1), and are unique to the overall ID. but I do not know the actual linkage and will need to do a manual record review to assign the linkages. To make my review quicker, I want to retain one of each of the subID's and one of each of the instances, like so:

```
   ID  subID  instance  feature  truesubID
1 1111   100        1       a       
2 1111   200        2       b       
3 1111   300        3       c       
4 1111   400        4       d       
5 2222   100        1       a       
6 2222   200        2       b       
7 2222   300        3       c       
8 2222   400        4       d
```

This way, when I do manual record review, I know what the possible subID numbers are, which ID they belong to, and I know how many instances to cross reference. I will then fill in the true subID into the last column. (e.g., subID=100 is really instance=4 for ID=1111, etc.)

Do you know how I could filter the first df to look like the second?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want more background on why the data is in this format - I did a left_join between my metadata sheet (with the features and instances) and my matching ID's and subID's. Since i don't know which instance goes with which subID, all possible combinations are returned during the join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pattern in your dataframe. You can remove every fifth row to get your desired result:

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  slice(which(row_number() %% 5 == 1))
```

Which gives you this:

[image]

**Edit:** due to extend information: a solution for if each ID has variable numbers of instances:**

```
df1 <- df %>%
  group_split(ID) %>%
  purrr::map_df(~.x %>% group_by(subID) %>% 
                  slice(cur_group_id())
                )
```

Comment: in an effort to make it straightforward I neglected to mention that not every ID has only 4 instances. some have 8, some have 5, etc. That is my fault for overlooking. Your answer is correct if each ID only had 4 unique instances. Thank you for your answer! 

Do you know a solution for if each ID has variable numbers of instances?

Comment: Please see my edit. It was hard ... but the edit should work.